# C++ Class template type std::list

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates

I have a thread safe queue class like below,

Class CmdQ:

```
template <typename Q>
class CmdQ
{
public:
    CmdQ() :
        queue_(),
        queueMutex_(){};
    ~CmdQ() {
        while (!queue_.empty()) {
            Q* element(std::move(this->queue_.front()));
            this->queue_.pop();
            delete element;
        }
    };
    void push(Q* commands) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queueMutex_);

        queue_.push(commands);
        this->mutexCondition_.notify_all();
    }
    void pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queueMutex_);
        while(this->queue_.empty())this->mutexCondition_.wait(lock);
        Q* element(std::move(this->queue_.front()));
        this->queue_.pop();
        delete element;
    }

    Q* front() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queueMutex_);
        while(this->queue_.empty())this->mutexCondition_.wait(lock);        if (!queue_.empty()) {
            return (queue_.front());
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    bool empty() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queueMutex_);
        return queue_.empty();
    }

    void clear() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queueMutex_);

        while (!queue_.empty()) {
            Q* element(std::move(this->queue_.front()));
            this->queue_.pop();
            delete element;
        }
    }

    unsigned int size() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queueMutex_);
        return queue_.size();
    }

private:
    std::queue queue_;
    std::mutex queueMutex_;
    std::condition_variable mutexCondition_;
};
```

Now, I want this queue to contain lists. And so, I used as below:

ClassB.h:

```
template<typename std::list<Message*>>
class CmdQ;

CmdQ<std::list<Message*>>* msgListQ_;
```

But, I keep getting the errors such as:

> Error 1   error C2993: 'std::list<_Ty>' : illegal type for non-type
>   template parameter '__formal'
>
> Error 3   error C2975: 'CmdQ' : invalid template argument for
>   'unnamed-parameter', expected compile-time constant expression

I referred to some documentation that template type cannot accept `std::list` but will accept pointer to lists and so also tried using pointer to list like below in ClassB.h:

```
template<typename std::list<Message*>*>
class CmdQ;

CmdQ<std::list<Message*>*>* msgListQ_;
```

But I still keep facing errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `std::queue queue_;` be `std::queue<Q> queue_;`?

Comment: You don't need the explicit instantiation anyway. You can just use the template to declare your variable.

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::queue<Q*> queue`, rather

Comment: `template<typename std::list<Message*>> class CmdQ;` is syntax from outer space. Why do you think you need this line at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the wrong part is the `typename` in

```
template<typename std::list<Message*>*>
class CmdQ;
```

try with

```
template <std::list<Message*>*>
class CmdQ;
```

or avoid it and simply write

```
CmdQ<std::list<Message*>*>* msgListQ_;
```

Anyway

> I referred to some documentation that template type cannot accept std::list

What?

a template class

```
template <typename>
class foo { };
```

doesn't accept `std::list` if you pass it without argument, as follows

```
foo<std::list>  fl0;
```

(because `std::list`, in this way, is a template-template argument) but accept it with arguments

```
foo<std::list<int>> fl1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I changed to "template <std::list<Message*>*> class CmdQ;" as mentioned and then used "CmdQ<std::list<Message*>*>* msgListQ_;". But, I still see the same Error 1 and Error 3 as I mentioned above. Any other insight on this?

Comment: @MonicaRajasekaran - have you tried to delete that and simply write `CmdQ<std::list<Message*>*>* msgListQ_;`?  Anyway, the problem can be in a question of header inclusion. Have you included (before) the header where `CmdQ` is implemented? Have you included the standard header `list`? I thing you should prepare a minimal, but complete, example to reproduce the error.

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thanks a ton. The forward declaration of that class messed me up.

Answer (score 2):

The class is broken (doesn't compile) because of the invalid

```
 std::queue queue_;
```

declaration. `std::queue` is a template and you need to supply a valid template argument.

Since you push and pop things of type `Q*`, the only declaration consistent with the rest of the template would be

```
 std::queue<Q*> queue_;
```

Now `CmdQ<std::list<Message*>*>` is **totally wrong** as the internal queue would store heap-allocated **pointers to pointers** of lists (that store pointers themselves). You certainly don't want that.

It's a bad design to constrain your queue class to work with pointers (and to own the pointed object) though. It makes little sense to limit the choice so severely. Raw C-style pointers are not recommended for general use, smart pointers should be preferred. It also makes little sense to move pointers. It also makes little sense to own a list, bit not its elements. If you remove all asterisks from the class, and also remove the call to `delete`, the template becomes simpler, more generic, and more consistent. You can then use

```
CmdQ<std::list<Message>>   // store lists by value
CmdQ<std::list<Message*>*> // store pointers to lists of pointers (not recommended)
CmdQ<std::unique_ptr<std::list<std::shared_ptr<Message>>>> // etc
```

or any combination you like. You will probably have to add a couple of calls to `std::move` here and there. You may also want to add an optional element deleter, just in case someone would want for some inexplicable reason to use your template with raw pointers.